# print the exact negative number in R

Tags: r

When I call x to do any calculation or just print the output I get extra values how can I ensure to print the same value
The output should be like this
-0.737, -0.532341, -0.494828, -0.31001234

```
x <- c(-0.737, -0.532341, -0.494828, -0.31001234)
x
OUTPUT 
[1] -0.7370000 -0.5323410 -0.4948280 -0.3100123
```

Comment: What is the difference between 0 and 0.00? Nothing. R has to maintain the same number of digits for every value within a vector. 0.737 is EXACTLY 0.7370000000. NOT CLOSE TO BUT RATHER EXACT/IDENTICAL. your question is therefore irrelevant

Comment: @onyambu 
as.character works fine but I can't use the x values in my calculation, these values are scaled value and when I reverse the scale I get the same result as the (before scale) but with the extra numbers, and it's not easy to read

Comment: For reading purposes, you can format to any notation, remove trailing zeros etc

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to view this data in the console without trailing 0s:

```
format(
  x, 
  drop0trailing = TRUE, 
  digits = max(
    nchar(x)
  )
)
```

Comment: I needed `formatC(x, digits = 8)` to get the OP's desired output.

Comment: @BenBolker ^ correct adjusted accordingly